# How to remote console error message in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, react-to-print

I'm using react-to-print in order to print a page.

It works fine but the page that is loaded contains some elements that have links (href).

So when I click on print, in console tab it shows the following error message:

> "react-to-print" was unable to load a linked node. It may be invalid.
> "react-to-print" will continue attempting to print the page. The
> linked node that errored was: ...

Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: Share the code block where you are facing the issue